Facing issues while setting up Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) as Identity Provider for AWS WorkSpaces using SAML 2.0?
I am trying to set up the Google SSO for AWS workspace access. We are already using Google SSO for AWS console access. SAML app in Google workspace is already present. Which we are using it for AWS console access.
Added
User Access URL https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=C03******
IdP deep link parameter name - optional: RelayState 

in AWS MS directory SAMl authentication setup.
I have created the AWS managed MS directory and enabled the SAML 2.0 authentication. When trying to login to workspace with Google email getting 400 error.
Following documentation from Google.
Google SAML app as below

Getting below error whille trying to login from AWS workspace.


Response from AWS support team
From case notes I understand that you are trying to set up the Google SSO for AWS workspace access and I do understand that you are currently using Google Single Sign-On (SSO) to access the AWS Management Console.
I would like to inform you that to use SAML 2.0 authentication with WorkSpaces, the identity provider (IdP) must support IdP-initiated deep linking for the relay state URL.
At this time, we are aware that Google Workspace do not support this capability and cannot be used with Amazon WorkSpaces SAML 2.0 integration.
Below article mentions a list of identity providers that do support IdP-initiated deep linking:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/setting-up-saml.html#
I hope this information proves useful. Please feel free to reach out if you have any further questions or concerns.
